# Multiple declaration for function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a function declared in my base class and specified as virtual, I am trying to re-declare it in a derived class but I'm getting a multiple declaration error.

Anyone know if I'm missing something here?

```
class Field {
    public:
        virtual void display() = 0;
        virtual int edit() = 0;
        virtual bool editable() const = 0;
        virtual void *data() = 0;
        virtual Field *clone() const = 0;
};

class LField : public Field {
        int rowNum;
        int colNum;
        int width;
        char *val;
        bool canEdit;
        int index;
    public:
        virtual void *data() { return val; }
};


class IVField : public LField { 

    void (*ptrFunc)(void *);
    bool (*ptrValid)(int &);
    int *data;

    public:
        void* data() { 
            return data;
        }

};

class DVField : public LField {
    int decimalsToDisplay;
    double *data;
    void (*ptrFunc)(void *);
    bool (*ptrValid)(double&);
    public:

        void* data() { 
            return data;
        }

};
```

Comment: It will be impossible for us to answer your question unless you show us your code.

Comment: Please re-add the code. Neither the question nor the answer makes any sense without it.

Comment: Note for posterity: it looks like the `intdata` and `dbldata` members were both named `data` originally, which caused the error.  Marcin: it's polite to leave the question in a form that could help others in the future.  By changing the code that generated the error, you've made it harder for others to learn something here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a function named `data` and a member variable named `data` in the same class. That's not allowed. Pick a different name for your member variable.

You also appear to be re-declaring many member variables. That's probably not what you want to do. If you want to declare them in the base class and use them in descendants, then they should probably have *protected* visibility. The default visibility for classes, when you haven't specified any other, is *private*, which means, for example, that descendants of `IVField` (such as `DVField`) cannot access the `ptrFunc` variable you declared in `IVField`. The `ptrFun` variable you declared in `DVField` has absolutely no relation to the one declared in the parent class. Make the `IVField` one protected, and then descendants don't need to duplicate the declaration for themselves.

You're also going to have to implement all those other abstract methods before the compiler will allow you to instantiate any of those classes.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. Thanks :) Will check mark when the timer is done.